# Reading MySQL Int(10) value in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect to mysql from C# WinForms program. Everything seems to be working fine, i get 99% of column values just fine just one `int` column doesn't want to return proper value:

```
   public static void getFromMySqlAndInsertIntoSql() {

        const string preparedCommand = @"
                    select *

                    from agreements";


        using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTimeMySql(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetailsMySQL))
        using (var sqlQuery = new MySqlCommand(preparedCommand, varConnection)) {
            using (var sqlQueryResult = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader())                 
                    while (sqlQueryResult.Read()) {
                        int agr_id = sqlQueryResult["agr_id"] is int ? (int)sqlQueryResult["agr_id"] : int.MinValue;
                        string agr_idTest = sqlQueryResult["agr_id"].ToString();
                        string agr_fname = sqlQueryResult["agr_fname"].ToString();
                        int agr_stocks_count = sqlQueryResult["agr_stocks_count"] is int ? (int)sqlQueryResult["agr_stocks_count"] : int.MinValue;
                        MessageBox.Show(agr_id.ToString(), agr_idTest);
                    }
             }
        }
}
```

`agr_id` always returns int.MinValue, but `agr_idTest` it returns proper string. `int` value for `agr_stocks_count` returns int properly so it doesn't seem to be the problem with code.

The only difference I can find in the MySQL table between first int column and the other is:

```
Field                Type     Collation   Attributes Null Default Extra   
 agr_id              int(10)              UNSIGNED   No   None    AUTO_INCREMENT    
 agr_stocks_count    int(11)                         No   None
```

Does anyone have explanation?

Comment: Is agr_id an int? I would think it is either uint or maybe ulong.

Comment: As you can see in MySql Table (column overview) it says int(10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int(10) on the DB does not map on int in C#. instead of using `is int`, try to use `System.Convert`.
ie use:

```
int agr_id = System.Convert.ToInt32(sqlQueryResult["agr_id"]);
```

Comment: An unsigned int in MYSQL can have a max value of 4294967295.  If the column contained that value, your solution would throw an overflow exception.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Your solution seems to work. However why other int values work normally and this one has to be converted?

Comment: @DarkBobG int column will most likely have max 10000 numbers, maybe a bit more.

Comment: @MadBoy no idea,but I would prefer always using Convert. as @darkbob pointed, using a long could solve teh problem even if you suppose to overflow the int.

Comment: Not sure who got you the -1 vote but it's only solution that seems to work.

Comment: @MadBoy Thanks:I know the solution just because I already had the same problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm i think for big integers it could twist over the maximal int value in C# and go to some negative values because the maximum value ot unsigned int is twise bigger than max value of ordinary int. Try it with long instead of int.

Comment: I really don't think is a twist, is that what you see in the db as an int(10) is probably returned as a decimal. So casting ad int does not work. System.Convert.Toxxxx is generally the best solution.

Comment: well the numbers now are 24, 25, 26 so nothing big

Comment: `long` returned same long.MinValue. System.Convert seems to work but I am wondering why `int` works fine for the other columns and not for the primary key

Comment: @Felice Pollano it's not long or decimal both return `MinValue`.

Comment: @MadBoy, again, use the convert, or do a get type in debug to see what really is. VConvert would work even if in the future you change the column type.

Answer (score -1):

`int index = sqlQueryResult.GetOrdinal("agr_id");

if (!sqlQueryResult.IsDbNull(index))

agr_id = sqlQueryResult.GetInt32(index);

else

agr_id = int.MinValue();`

Comment: since column is not nullable there is no need to check for null.